# What is the remainder if the summation of three consecutive numbers is divided by $3$

Tags: number-theory, summation

> What is the remainder after division if the summation of three consecutive numbers is divided by $3$?

How to solve this sum?

How do I find the remainder?

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{SUM} =n + (n+1) + (n+2)  =  3(n+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the first number be $a$. Then your sum is $$a+(a+1)+(a+2)=3a+3=3(a+1).$$If $a$ is an integer, this is divisible by $3$. So your remainder will be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the three consecutive numbers be $N,N+1,N+2$ so the sum is $3N +3$.

It is always divisible by three. So the reminder is $0$.